# Can a differential equation have a solution, but not a maximal solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The title says it all.

Is there a differential equation $D$ which admits a solution $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is not maximal ($I$ is strictly contained in the domain of $D$, so $f$ solves $D$ restricted to $I$), and for every $g$, a maximal solution of $D$, we have that $g(x) \ne f(x)$ for all $x\in I$?

NB: Special interest is put on linear differential equations.

Comment: Like $I=(-\infty,1)$, the ODE $y'=y^2$, with $f$ the IVP solution with $f(0)=0.5$ and $g$ the IVP solution for $g(0)=1$?

Comment: Or seen from another angle, if the domain of the ODE is $I\times\Bbb R$, then any solution with domain $I$ is automatically maximal (for that ODE domain).

Comment: (I will clarify this in the Q) The domain of the ODE is strictly larger than I. Thus: f is a solution of a restriction of the equation to I, each g is a maximal solution of the "full" ODE, and the restriction of g to I is not pointwise equal to f.

Comment: With the changes now, what prevents you to take $g$ as the maximal extension of $f$? On $I$, both would obviously be equal.

Comment: Yes, but what's the proof that a maximal extension exists? I'm an undergrad, so sorry if it's trivial, but it doesn't seem so trivial to me.

Comment: That proof is usually done via a projective limit over all solutions of an IVP, that is, via a very abstract argument. Then properties of the maximal domain are derived, largely saying that the limit (including divergence) of the maximal solution at the interval ends has to be at the boundary of the domain. For linear DE this is much more simple, the maximal domain of the solution is the maximal open interval around the initial point where the coefficients are continuous.